# Facebook user not able to login getting error "Remote site 5XX from facebook.com for USER_INFO"

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api

I have a website in which i use facebook authentication via firebase auth.
There are couple of users that have logged in to website and are registered and have granted app permissions.

After some time we added "ads_management" permission for some users so that they'll have  access to manage ads.
But after some time users started facing problems with login with facebook(only users that gave ads_management permission have been affected so far) and after entering their credentials started getting this error

> Remote site 5XX from facebook.com for USER_INFO.

And they are not able to login.
What does this error mean?
And how to get this resolved?

I tried creating new user and signing up and that seems to be working.
The issue is only with old users.

What's expected is that user should be able to login with facebook

Comment: did you solve this?